# How to select value in md-select with formcontrolname in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material, md-select

I am using react form and angular material's md-select .

This is my form

```
<md-select placeholder="Parent Category" class="full-width" formControlName="parent_id">
  <md-option>None</md-option>
  <md-option *ngFor="let category of plainCategories" [value]="category.id">
    <span *ngIf="category.subcategory.length==0">&nbsp;</span>{{ category.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

I want to set md-select value from code and this is what i have tried

```
onClicked(e){
  if (e && e.action == 'edit') {

    let item = {
      id: e.item.id,
      name: e.item.name,
      slug: e.item.slug,
      parent_id: e.item.parent_id
    };

    this.categoryForm.setValue(item);
  }
}
```

This is updating the form value (`{{categoryForm.val | json}}` shows the value set) but the select option is not showing the option as selected. How can i select the md-option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if set of fields to be updated is not full as declared in the form (for example if there is also element called `category`, besides `id`, `name`, `slug` and `parent_id`), then `setValue()` will not work, use `patchValue()` instead:

```
this.categoryForm.patchValue(item);
```

you also can set value per field:

```
this.categoryForm.get('parent_id').setValue(e.item.parent_id);
```

see my example plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PftFkCQ5fvLICczt7gAO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is perfectly working in the plnkr when the value is string. But my parent_id is number thats why md-option is not selected . How could i make the number selectable?

Comment: updated my plunker, widh numeric IDs, it may work also with complex objects if needed. Please update my plunker if you need further help and I will try to help